# How to check if all float columns in a Pandas DataFrame are approximately equal or close

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with 12 columns. In those I have many float columns, which I need to verify that the values are approximately equal or close enough.

Sample Data:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'id' : ['abc', 'pqr', 'xyz', 'cbz'],
                  'col1' : [0.0234, 0.001852, 4.123, 0.0012],
                  'col2' : [0.0235, 0.001851, 0.0123, 0.0013],
                  'col3' : [0.0233, 0.001849, 0.124, 0.0011]})
df

    id  col1      col2      col3
0   abc 0.0234    0.0235    0.0233
1   pqr 0.001852  0.001851  0.001849
2   xyz 4.123     0.0123    0.124
```

I can use `np.isclose` and set a threshold that is applicable in my case, which would be 0.062. But can someone please let me know how to compare if col1 is approximately equal to col2 approximately equal to col3. If even 1 column doesn't satisfy the condition, the result should be `False` as in the case of `id` `xyz`.

Comment: Is it sufficient to check if `min` across all columns and `max` across all columns for a particular row are "close"?

Comment: @Mortz, yeah should be good enough

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can compare all transpose column by first and test if all values are `True`s by [`numpy.all`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.all.html):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'id' : ['abc', 'pqr', 'xyz', 'cbz'],
                  'col1' : [0.0234, 0.001852, 4.123, 0.0012],
                  'col2' : [0.0235, 0.001851, 0.0123, 0.0013],
                  'col3' : [0.0233, 0.001849, 0.124, 0.0011]})

cols= ['col1','col2','col3']

out = np.isclose(df[cols[1:]].to_numpy(), 
                 df[cols[0]].to_numpy()[:, None], 
                 atol=0.062).all(axis=1)
print (out)
[ True  True False  True]

print (df.loc[out, 'id'])
0    abc
1    pqr
3    cbz
Name: id, dtype: object
```

Comment: Not sure if it works with different dimensions. my actual df contains like 6 float columns and 90k rows. Have added additional row to my original dataset, could you please have a look

Comment: @KarthikS - added parameter `atol` and change solution

Comment: need another help, I've got few `NaN` in my data. I want the `np.isclose` to ignore them. Don't see that as one of the options. could you please help with the code in that scenario

Comment: @KarthikS - If there are `NaN`s, then np.isloce return `False`, do you need `True`? Eg. in `df = pd.DataFrame({'id' : ['abc', 'pqr', 'xyz', 'cbz'],
                  'col1' : [0.0234, 0.001852, np.nan, 0.0012],
                  'col2' : [0.0235, 0.001851, np.nan, 0.0013],
                  'col3' : [0.0233, 0.001849, np.nan, 0.0011]})` ?

Comment: like this `import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame({'id' : ['abc', 'pqr', 'xyz', 'cbz'],
                  'col1' : [0.0234, 0.001852, 4.123, 0.0012],
                  'col2' : [0.0235, np.nan, 0.0123, 0.0013],
                  'col3' : [0.0233, 0.001849, 0.124, 0.0011]})
df` for `id` `pqr` the answer should be yes, if we ignore the `nan`

Comment: @KarthikS - I got it. Before my solution use `df = df.ffill(axis=1).bfill(axis=1)` - it replace missing values per rows. Then apply my solution.

Comment: Ah ok, easy fix. thanks! BTW I've seen either `ffill` or `bfill`, could you please tell why both?

Comment: @KarthikS - It is if first or last column is filled by NaN, first column replace bfill, last column ffill.

Answer (score 1):

IIUC, you can use :

```
thresh = 0.062

arr = df.set_index("id").to_numpy()

diff = np.abs(arr[:, :, None] - arr[:, None, :])

m = np.all(diff <= thresh, axis=(1, 2))
```

Output :

```
>>> m
# array([ True,  True, False,  True])

>>> df["id"].loc[~m].values
# array(['xyz'], dtype=object)
```

Answer (score 0):

Comprehensive list using `np.isclose` and then combining boolean arrays with `np.logical_and` :

```
float_columns = df.select_dtypes(float).columns
condition = np.logical_and(
    *[np.isclose(df[previous_column], df[next_column], atol=0.062)
    for previous_column, next_column in zip(float_columns[:-1], float_columns[1:])]
)
>>> condition
array([ True,  True, False])
```